# dm-crypt cryptsetup using cryptodev module

Tags: cryptsetup

I have introduced the usage of cryptsetup to encrypt a portion of the disk space, but the writing speed is very slow. I found that there is a module to utilize directly the hardware for the encryption operations, using the module cryptodev.
I have installed the cryptodev and just running

```
openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc -engine cryptodev
```

I tested the writing speed with

```
time dd bs=5000k count=1 if=/dev/zero of=/home/... conv=fsync
```

before and after including the cryptodev module and with this control I can't see any improvement. There are other things to define for cryptsetup to use this engine? Thanks

[edit]---------------------------------------------

```
$ cryptsetup luksDump DISK --debug
# cryptsetup 1.7.0 processing "cryptsetup luksDump DISK --debug"
# Running command luksDump.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating crypt device DISK context.
# Trying to open and read device DISK with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load LUKS1 crypt type from device DISK.
# Crypto backend (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016) initialized in cryptsetup library version 1.7.0.
# Detected kernel Linux 4.1.15-xuelk-2.0.1-dirty armv7l.
# Reading LUKS header of size 1024 from device DISK
# Key length 32, device size 204800 sectors, header size 2050 sectors.
LUKS header information for DISK

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    cbc-essiv:sha256
Hash spec:      sha256
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      00 a6 fb a5 64 1d 08 47 9d ea 76 d3 34 f2 19 cf 66 b7 e7 94 
MK salt:        8c 14 4e 3a 97 d6 d7 18 ca 46 f9 f0 47 d5 44 3f 
                46 0c c5 4e d7 35 1d 46 ca 2b fc af 13 14 d1 98 
MK iterations:  13500
UUID:           a808c328-0c0e-43a7-9057-b6b9a49afeb9

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
        Iterations:             108472
        Salt:                   76 be 3e a1 5f 37 9b bc 1b 84 69 9e 36 db 5f ba 
                                43 93 96 34 57 02 59 df 2c 19 f4 df 1a 09 53 7a 
        Key material offset:    8
        AF stripes:             4000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `cryptsetup` basically just configures the `dm-crypt` kernel module. That means that the encrypting/decrypting of your disk happens inside the kernel. The kernel doesn't use openssl, at all.

You can reliably test the current hard disk encryption performance with:

```
cryptsetup benchmark
```

The [cryptsetup defaults are aes-xts, 256b](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Encryption_options_for_LUKS_mode), when creating the encrypted device with `cryptsetup luksCreate` (cf. the `cryptsetup luksDump` output).

Some experimental results from medium scale hardware:

```
CPU                       cryptsetup benchmark
AMD Phenom 9750 2.4 GHz   aes-xts   256b   146.7 MiB/s   148.5 MiB/s
Intel Atom C3758 2.2 GHz  aes-xts   256b   874.0 MiB/s   875.4 MiB/s
Intel i5-4250U 1.3 GHz    aes-xts   256b  1703.3 MiB/s  1723.1 MiB/s
Intel i7-6600U 2.6 GHz    aes-xts   256b  2978.0 MiB/s  3117.5 MiB/s
```

The Linux kernel contains several drivers for hardware that accelerates crypto operations. Usually, they are loaded, by default and used by the kernel's crypto subsystem.

For example, newer Intel CPUs come with the [AES-NI instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) that significantly speed up AES - you can check if the CPU supports them like this:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < /proc/cpuinfo | grep aes
```

Some systems even come with crypto co-processors (cf. e.g. [Intel QuickAssist - QAT](https://01.org/intel-quickassist-technology)). They may speed things up, but can also slow things down - thus, when benchmarking, it makes sense to check the boot logs if such special hardware is configured by the kernel and if the necessary modules/firmware is loaded. If such hardware is present it makes sense to check the performance with co-processor enabled vs. disabled (e.g. via blacklisting the relevant `*qat*` modules).

Comment: Vey useful unswer, but you say that cryptsetup doesn't use at all openssl? Do you have some reference for this information? I understand that indeed openssl was used as back-end.

Comment: @G.D., yes, this is what I wrote. The `cryptsetup` program just runs for a short time. After it has finished it's the kernel's job to transparently encrypt/decrypt each written/read block. The kernel simply isn't able to call a library like openssl. You can also look at the cryptsetup source code to see how it works. `cryptsetup` doesn't even link openssl (cf. `ldd` output for cryptsetup/libcryptsetup). When you strace `cryptsetup benchmark` you see how it talks to the kernel over a socket for its crypto operations. See also e.g. [dm-crypt (WP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt).

Comment: I tust you, but at some point openssl is called in the backend. I added the dump of one disk I created where is reported openssl as backend. Do you also know what that backend is for? I wasn't able to find an answer

Comment: @G.D., you don't have to trust me - you can verify the reasoning I've described. And read the article I've linked. The `cryptsetup` needs to perform some elementary crypto operations when writing/reading the header of the encrypted device - e.g. when formatting or opening the device. This happens in user-space and your version seems to use openssl for this - my version uses gcrypt. But once the device is mapped by the kernel, `cryptsetup` has exited and all the de-/encryption for each read/write happens inside the kernel. Thus, openssl (or any other user space lib) is out of the picture.

Comment: Thanks again. I verified all, and now results have sense.